# Where do you study?

Tags: ellipsis

What is the correct reply to *Where do you study?*

1. *At the library.*
2. *The library.*

Answer (score 2):

You could be *at the library*, *in the library* or just *the library.* English is pretty flexible with these things.

Answer (score 2):

The full sentence is "I study at the library". "At the library" is [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) already. So there's no reason to not elide even further and say "The library". And indeed people often do just that. This is not limited to English, by the way.